# What is the best way to level up Frames in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

I am looking to level up my Frames the most efficient way possible. Doing grineer mission of low levels does not yield much experience and it is becoming too tedious.

I have 4 unranked frames left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way by far is to go to a rep farm with other players. Examples of popular nodes are Draco - Ceres (Interception), Stephano - Uranus (Interception)

Make sure you have a party that is able to rep farm efficiently (currently a Mesa - Mesa - Buffer/Nekros - Greedy Pull Mag).  You can easily get weapons from 0-30 in 2-3 waves, frames from 0-30 in 4-5 waves.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was caught up with my work. Draco seems to be the most efficient way, but I lack too many mods that even though I have my own Excal I am not able to do much by myself.

Comment: @Rai If you don't have many good mods, message me in game. I'd be happy to get you some mods free of charge.  Just lemme know what your Wf username will be. id: retrosaur

Comment: Do you have any advice with the new map change?

Answer (score 3):

Since Draco has been brutally murdered by DE the answer to this question has changed. People have found various nodes as replacements for Draco. The most popular are currently;

- Berehynia, Sedna
- Hydron, Sedna
- Akkad, Eris

I personally prefer Berehynia as it has the highest enemy spawn on the star chart, a distinction that was previously held by Draco. This means that time-wise with the appropriate squad, Berehynia is currently the most effecient way to level stuff in warframe at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try Orokin Derelict Defense (ODD for short).
Gives lot's of experience if you do a great amount  of waves, it was easy to upgrade my nekros this way.
Also, try Interception, this mode spawns lots of eximuses who give about 600-700 xp each.

Answer (score 0):

spy missions, mainly tier 3 spy missions. since its a spy mission, you dont need to equip all of your weapons, which will help you level your warframe up faster and each data hacked will give you a great amount of exp.

Answer (score -1):

For frames, I'd recommend a Tower 1 Defense. They don't take much work and there are always a lot of people willing to do them. Orokin Derelict Defense is ok, but it's much more difficult now due to the TAR Moas.

The biggest thing to keep in mind is that more enemies = more experience. Interception is great for getting tons of enemies but it can take a very specific group of people (draco currently "requires" 2 excalibers, a trinity, and a rhino) so you would be hard pressed finding a group that lets you level a frame. The interception method is great for leveling weapons though, so don't be afraid to throw on something low leveled to snag some extra experience.

Comment: Tower Defense I is painfully slow.  Enemy levels are low, so you receive lower exp amounts, as opposed to doing a T4 or an ODD.

Comment: @memescientist - Rai asked for the most efficient way. While T1D is not the fastest way to level up a frame, it is very efficient to do so. Going into a T4D will severely limit the amount of time you can stay in the mission, reducing the amount of enemies you kill and length you can stay. In a T1D (or even T2D) you can easily stay upwards of 40 waves because you don't need to deal with bombards and nullifiers. That being said, this is also a highly opinionated answer. Some people prefer ODD, I don't because there are no safe spots from the TAR MOAs and your team spends more time reviving you.

Comment: Several points. On ODD there are 4 spots that are immune to tar moa shots.  Most squads can easily run 20-40 rounds of defense on T4.   T1 is nice but the exp rewards make it less efficient, as you need multiple T1s just to get close to the exp from a T4.

Comment: I don't know why I even bother trying to reason with you anymore. You're absolutely adamant that your way is the only way and every other way is wrong, its ridiculous.

Comment: To test out your theory I brought a Rank 0 frame, along with rank 0 weapons to a T1 defense. It took me near 40 waves to get close to rank 15, this was without the use of boosters. I brought another set of unranked frames and weapons, and brought them to a T4 Defense.  Levelled up to 15 by wave 20.  Huge difference there.

Comment: It took me 2 waves: that's a little under 10 minutes, of a Draco Ceres interception to get my rank 0 weapons and frame to 24 and 17 respectively. It took me 40 waves of a T1 Defense (around 45 minutes), to get my frame to level 12, and my weapons to level 15.